# How can I parse a Widget to an Image UInt8List

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a profile image that I am using FadeInImage.memoryNetwork to load.

```
     ClipOval(
      child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
        image: imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.fill,
        width: 160,
        height: 160,
      ),
    ),
```

[image: profile image]

However, instead of a placeholder image "kTransparentImage", I want to create something from the user's initials. Sometihng like below, But I want to convert it to fit where **kTransparentImage** is in the code above, and this is a **UInt8List**.

```
    ClipOval(
      child: Container(
        width: 160,
        height: 160,
        color: Colors.blue,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 40),
        child: Text(
          "L M",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 70),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

[image: placeholder image]

Comment: So, where's the problem ?

Comment: @Nitesh I want to be able to use a Widget as a placeholder

Comment: why can't we just have the widget as a widget and replace the 'FadeInImage' with the initials ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this library, it supports widget as placeholder:
https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image